# Filtering subreport trough event procedure doesn't work

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013, subreport, onload-event

I have main report and unbound subreport. Both use the same query. I setup onload event procedure to turn on filter in subreport.

**Problem:** Onload procedure works fine when I open subreport separately. But when I open main report, procedure doesn’t work in subreport and instead of few filtered records, subreport displays all data from a query.

**Question:** How can I run filter in subreport?

**Important:** 
Subreport is placed in the main report’s header, so it won’t be bound with any field of main report (I use subreport as a table of contents for the main report).

I open report in print preview.

Comment: Being able to read your code is helpful to understand your issue. Could you post the OnLoad sub?

Comment: Yes, sure. This is the code I use in the subform: Me.Filter = Forms!MyForm.Form.Filter
FilterOn = True

Comment: I mean in the subreport of course, sorry.

Comment: you can't use subreports load event, but you can use the main report load event and refer to the subform `Me!myReportControlName.Report.Filter = Forms!MyForm.Form.Filter Me!myReportControlName.Report.FilterOn = True`

Comment: @BitAccesser, your solution works, thank you very much! The only thing I had to change is path to the Subreport. Version with `Me!` for some reason generates an error in my case. I use `Reports!MyMainReport!MySubReport.Report.Filter` instead and that eliminates the problem. Kudos.